# Interpolate y-value of a d3.svg.line at a given x-value

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

If I have a line (possibly with some spline interpolation specified), can I extract the interpolated y-value at a given x-value?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but there's not yet a built-in facility for doing so. All of D3’s splines are implemented as piecewise quadratic or cubic Bézier curves (because they are rendered to SVG path elements). You can use [de Casteljau's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm) for computing the *xy*-coordinates for a given parameter *t* in [0,1].

It's a bit harder to compute *y* for a given *x* because it's possible to have multiple *y* values for the same *x*, depending on the curve. For that, I recommend looking at this [Bézier curves primer](http://processingjs.nihongoresources.com/bezierinfo/) which describes an algorithm for computing a curve-line intersection; this could be simplified for a vertical line (constant *x*).